# Android - Stretch canvas/bitmap to full screen width

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have a canvas in which i'm drawing a lot of bitmaps. 15x15, to be exact.

Now, what i want to do is ensure that these 15 columns of bitmaps, back to back, stretch across the entire width of the screen. But since 160/15 isn't an integer number, i can't just set the width of them to the appropriate value.

Is there any way to stretch them, or perhaps the whole canvas, to fit the screen snugly?

Thanks.

Comment: bitmaps of tiny sizes such as 15x15 typically don't scale very well, especially if you try to stretch them to 16x16! (15x15 being an odd size to start with btw).  Scaling the whole canvas is typically not a good idea either if it's only to strectch by a few pixels.  However you could create an area a bit bigger than the screen and only draw the visible part of your area: doing so also helps dodging a lot of clipping problems etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used canvas.scale(float scaleX, float scaleY) to make the canvas, and its contents, stretch to the width of the screen.

Comment: If you use this method inside onDraw method a lot of CPU time will be used each time the method is called. I suggest you apply the matrix.postScale explained by Emmanuel Sys above only for the very first time and then re-use the resized bitmap as a class field...

Comment: @A.Masson So if you use this method only once it's okay?

Comment: I think so. The idea is to keep a bitmap instance variable which you can then compute and once and then reuse on all subsequent onDraw calls which occur frequently (multiple calls per second)

Answer (score 4):

You can resize a Bitmap using a `Matrix` object.

```
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
```

Comment: How would I know what newHeight or newWidth is? How do I figure out the screen size so I can change the canvas size to it?